# Como retornar registro vazio de um Select?

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou criando um sistema em **PHP** e nele possui um **Script** que faz a seleção dos dados do módulo solicitado pelo usuário. O **Script** cria o formulário para exibir e editar os dados conforme as informações dos campos das tabelas. O problema que estou enfrentando é que quando a requisição é uma inclusão de registro, ainda preciso que seja feito um **Select** na tabela para que os campos do formulário sejam exibidos corretamente, ao qual não está acontecendo. Preciso que a consulta retorne um registro vazio para que o **Script** possa ler as informações dos campos.

O **Select** é o seguinte:

```
select ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS where (ID = 0)
```

Já tentei de várias formas, mas quando não retorna nenhum, retorna todos:

```
select null, ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS where (ID = 0) //Não retorna nada
select ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS where (ID = 0) or (1=1) //Retorna todos os registros
select ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS where (ID = 0) and (1=1) //Não retorna nada
select coalesce(ID,''), coalesce(DATA,''), coalesce(DESCRICAO,'') from FERIADOS where (ID = 0) //Não retorna nada
select first 1 ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS //Eu poderia utilizar esse, mas há casos de tabelas vazias e ainda terei que zerar os valores dos campos
```

Pensei em criar **Stored Procedure** para deixar vazio cada campo caso a consulta fosse vazia, mas fica inviável a manutenção do código, pois eu teria que criar uma **SP** pra cada tabela e a idéia do projeto já é usar apenas um **Script** pra cada tipo de requisição.

Qual função eu poderia adicionar no Select para que a consulta mostre os campos mesmo que retorne nenhum registro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Editada, Detalhamento.
>
> Com essa versão voce consegue as informações de forma detalhada sobre os campos:

```
SELECT 
    r.RDB$FIELD_NAME AS field_name,
    r.RDB$DESCRIPTION AS field_description,
    r.RDB$DEFAULT_VALUE AS field_default_value,
    r.RDB$NULL_FLAG AS field_not_null_constraint,
    f.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH AS field_length,
    f.RDB$FIELD_PRECISION AS field_precision,
    f.RDB$FIELD_SCALE AS field_scale,
CASE f.RDB$FIELD_TYPE
    WHEN 261 THEN 'BLOB'
    WHEN 14 THEN 'CHAR'
    WHEN 40 THEN 'CSTRING'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'D_FLOAT'
    WHEN 27 THEN 'DOUBLE'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'FLOAT'
    WHEN 16 THEN 'INT64'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'INTEGER'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'QUAD'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'SMALLINT'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'DATE'
    WHEN 13 THEN 'TIME'
    WHEN 35 THEN 'TIMESTAMP'
    WHEN 37 THEN 'VARCHAR'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END AS field_type,
    f.RDB$FIELD_SUB_TYPE AS field_subtype,
    coll.RDB$COLLATION_NAME AS field_collation,
    cset.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS field_charset
FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS r
    LEFT JOIN RDB$FIELDS f ON r.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = f.RDB$FIELD_NAME
    LEFT JOIN RDB$COLLATIONS coll ON f.RDB$COLLATION_ID = coll.RDB$COLLATION_ID
    LEFT JOIN RDB$CHARACTER_SETS cset ON f.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID = cset.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID
WHERE 
    r.RDB$RELATION_NAME='NOME_TABELA'  
ORDER BY 
    r.RDB$FIELD_POSITION;
```

Para selecionar apenas os nomes dos campos de uma tabela em SQL, faça:

```
SELECT 
    RDB$FIELD_NAME
FROM 
    RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
WHERE 
    RDB$RELATION_NAME='NOME_TABELA'
```

**Observação:**

Usava isso no FB 2.1, já faz um bom tempo, mas deve funcionar nas versões atuais.

Comment: Sidon, desta forma funcionaria sim, mas no meu caso eu precisaria mesmo de uma forma que os campos viessem no Select da tabela. É que o Select é único, mas se eu não conseguir alguma sugestão de uma função que eu poderia utilizar nele, vou utilizar seu exemplo. Obrigado!

Comment: É só verificar se vei vazio, utilizar o exemplo e criar o form. Vou editar para que vc consiga informações mais detalhadas sobre os campos

Comment: Você tem alguma idéia do que eu poderia acrescentar na cláusula `where` do meu Select para que retorne uma consulta vazia? Por ex: `select ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS where (ID = 0) or ?????`

Comment: Ok Sidon, muito obrigado pelo tempo dedicado. Vou adaptar seu código, com certeza dará certo.

Comment: Cara, nunca vi isso, parece estranho ao conceito do `SELECT` do SQL. A única forma que consigo imaginar sem criar procedures no banco, seria criando registros 'vazios' nas tabelas.

Comment: Esqueça a forma que vc fazia e use meu exemplo para montar o formularios, antes mesmo de fazer a consulta "real". É dessa forma que criavamos formularios dinamicos quando eu usava FB. :-)

Answer (score 0):

cara , acho que você esta fazendo do jeito errado.
você não precisa saber tem os campos mas se o numero de linhas que retornou é maior que zero.
para trazer qualquer retorno algo você deve buscar e que tenha conteúdo. o sgbd não irá trazer a sua consulta totalmente vazia.

> Preciso que a consulta retorne um registro vazio para que o Script possa ler as informações dos campos.

Acredito que você esta lendo o seu texto da forma errada se você quer um registro vazio, faz um insert e depois exibe os dados não preenchidos, mas ao meu ver isso é completamente errado.
Eu sugiro que você verifique sem tem alguma linha se tiver preenche com o que veio , se não vier nada, não preenche nada.

Comment: Gustavo, sei exatamente o que você quis dizer. Deixa eu te explicar melhor. Eu não tenho um formulário html já pronto para exibir/editar os dados. To querendo criar o formulário dinamicamente. Por ex: O usuário clicou no menu: "Cadastro de Feriados", então o Script irá montar o formulário conforme os campos existentes na tabela "FERIADOS" e assim funciona para cada módulo. Já criei todas as funções para tratar cada tipo de campo. Este problema é apenas na hora da inserção dos dados, pois eu preciso que o Select retorne um resultado com os campos vazios.

Comment: ... Para então dar continuidade e montar o formulário HTML conforme os tipos de campos da tabela. Este Script já funciona para visualizar/alterar dados, mas só preciso agora para a inserção.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade, minha resposta não atende? vc pode montar o formulario baseado nos nomes dos campos, não?

Answer (score 0):

Tentando aqui, lembrei do `UNION` que já usava em alguns casos. Fiz uma adaptação no Select e acabou dando certo, mas ainda assim considero a resposta do @Sidon a mais adequada, só resolvi utilizar este por questão de adaptação ao meu código, pois ficará menos trabalhoso na manutenção do mesmo.

```
select ID, DATA, DESCRICAO from FERIADOS where (ID = 0)
union all
select NULL, NULL, NULL from rdb$database
```

O primeiro Select não retornará nada por causa do valor 0 passado propositalmente ao campo ID. Já o segundo Select após o `union all` irá retornar um registro vazio. Neste caso, a quantidade de colunas deve ser igual em ambos os Selects.